# How to assign key as well as value to model object in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I am doing project in Laravel. I want to assign some fields whose column keys as well as values are same in multiple tables. Like I have common fields like created_by,updated_by,status fields as common in almost every table.

I have create array of these key values,

```
$common_data     = ['status' => Constants::ACTIVE,'created_by' => 1,'updated_by' => 1];
```

Every time when I create new object of model I have to manually assign them to this object like,

```
$intake = new Intake($data);
$intake->name = 'test;
$intake->email = 'test@gmail.com;
$intake->status = Constants::ACTIVE;
$intake->created_by = 1;
$intake->updated_by = 1;
```

and save() will be somewhere else.

So instead of having this, Is there any way to add these common fields to the object. Like some push operation or something else.

Comment: I presume that you could define a model method `setDefaults()` or similar to set common values?

Comment: but here created_by could be from any table

Comment: OK, so add that method into a trait, and add it into any model that you want it to affect.

Comment: Ok ill try this

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to model event such saving, creating, etc by using callback method. These functions are fired when such events are occurred. Take look at the code below

```
class Intake extends Model {
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::creating(function ($intake ) {
        $intake->status = Constants::ACTIVE;
        $intake->created_by = 1;
        $intake->updated_by = 1;
    });
}}
```

[Try look at Laravel event documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#events)